Why can't we add interactive sever on Login page in Individual accounts identity in blazor server app?
I have Blazor server web app we use identity platform so i need to add JS functionalities to Login Page But I cant add those things without adding interactive render mode in blazor but if it not working for the Login Page.
I try removing Httpcontext and also map a another end point in the IdentityComponentsEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions also but the error was still the same.

Is your Login page a razor component (.razor) or a razor page (.cshtml)? RenderModes aren't supported in razor pages.

login page need SSR which js interop doesn't work. Why do you need js?

@Jonathan its a razor page .razor

@QiangFu need some sort of vallidations using js and need to add methods like oninput in blazor edit form

What error do you get?

22T09:55:27.956Z] Error: System.InvalidOperationException: Headers are read-only, response has already started.
@Jonathan

Ok, it's been a while since I used Blazor, but this is what I remember:
You can't make a page which requires authentication be InteractiveServer. That's because of a few reasons:

All code is executed on the server side which doesn't have access to the client side cookies.
InteractiveServer uses SignalR, which in it's core uses WebSockets. WebSockets send headers (and thus cookies) only once per connection, but the connection is re-used while the page is open. This means no new data can be added to the headers without a full page refresh, but that would defeat the point of Blazor.

You can still add JavaScript to a InteractiveWebAssembly page though by injecting the IJSInterop interface and using it in OnAfterRenderAsync:
<!-- LoginComponent.razor -->
@rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly
@inject IJSRuntime javascript

<!-- your blazor code -->

@code {
    public override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync()
    {
        await javascript.InvokeVoidAsync("your method", "your parameters");
    }
}

When you use ServerPrerendered, you can import the JS in the  tag like so:
<!-- LoginComponent.razor -->
<HeadContent>
    <script src="/js/validation.js"></script>
</HeadContent>

<!-- your blazor code -->

This will result in the script tag to be added to the pages <head> element.
